# System.Collections.Generic.List ERROR!

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema al crear una lista.

```
public static List StackHERE = new List();
```

Así la inicio, pero me da error en el List. (Estoy usando el `using System.Collections.Generic;`)

> **Error    CS0305  El uso de tipo de tipo genérico 'List' requiere argumentos de tipo 1.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que indicar el tipo de los objetos que habrá en la lista. Por ejemplo, si la lista va a contener valores numéricos enteros, sería tal que así:

```
public static List<int> StackHERE = new List<int>();
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, mis objetos eran string así que e ahí la solución.